# What is the simplest way to train pytroch-lightning model over a bunch of servers with Dask?

Tags: machine-learning, dask, distributed-computing, pytorch-lightning, ddp

I have access to a couple dozens Dask servers without GPU but with complete control of the software (can wipe them and install something different) and want to accelerate pytorch-lightning model training.
What could be a possible solution to integrate them with as little additional code possible?

I've researched this topic a bit, finding possible options, cannot determine which one to choose:

| # | option | info | pro | con |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | [dask-pytorch-ddp](https://github.com/saturncloud/dask-pytorch-ddp) | Package to be used to writing models with easier integration into Dask | will likely work | cannot use existing model out of the box, need rewriting the model itself |
| 2. | [PL docs, on-prem cluster (intermediate)](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/clouds/cluster_intermediate_1.html) | multiple copies of pytorch lighning on the network | simples way according to lightning docs | fiddly to launch according to the docs |
| 3. | [PL docs, SLURM cluster](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/clouds/cluster_advanced.html#run-on-a-slurm-managed-cluster) | wipe/redeploy cluster, setup SLURM | less fiddly to launch individual jobs | need to redeploy the cluster OS/software |
| 4. | [Pytorch + dask](https://ml.dask.org/pytorch.html) | officially supported and documented use of Skorch | has a package handling this - skorch | will need to use pytorch, not lightning |

Are there any more options or tutorials to learn about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend looking into Horovod for this. [Horovod](https://horovod.ai/) is a distributed deep learning training framework for TensorFlow, Keras, PyTorch, and Apache MXNet. You can use the [Horovod integration with PyTorch Lightning](https://horovod.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pytorch.html#pytorch-lightning) to distribute the training of your model. This approach will require installing Horovod on your servers and minimal changes to your existing PyTorch Lightning code.

As an alternative, you can also consider using [Ray for distributed training with PyTorch Lightning](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-more-libs/using-ray-with-pytorch-lightning.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for many suggestions. Those are the ones I have not found at first,  but looks promising. Will update my comments based on my results